# We are not able to set customized passwordFilter in windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, visual-c++, desktop-application

I created my own password filter.dll, but I am not able to set it into Windows system.

I appended it under LSA->Notificationpackage, and I copied into c:\Window\System32 as well.

In my password filter, at start I created the log file, but it is not creating it.

Please let me know is there are any more steps I need to perform to set my password filter in Windows 10.

Please find this snippet of my password filter:

```
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>
#include "Ntsecapi.h"
#define MAX_SIZE 4028

using namespace std;
using namespace std::tr1;

fstream writeLog;

BOOLEAN __stdcall InitializeChangeNotify(void)
{
    wchar_t *pLogFile = L"c:\AmitPasswordFilter.log";
    wchar_t aLogFileExp[64];
    ExpandEnvironmentStrings(pLogFile, aLogFileExp, sizeof(aLogFileExp)/sizeof(wchar_t));

    writeLog.open(aLogFileExp, ios::out|ios::app);
    writeLog<<"InitializeChangeNotify"<<endl;

    return TRUE;
}

BOOLEAN __stdcall PasswordFilter(PUNICODE_STRING AccountName, PUNICODE_STRING FullName, PUNICODE_STRING Password, BOOLEAN SetOperation)
{
    writeLog<<"BabaPasswordFilter"<<endl;
    writeLog<< "PasswordFilterAmit"<<endl;

    wcmatch mr;
    BOOL match = FALSE;
    std::wstring seperator(L")(?=");
    std::wstring regExp(L"(?=");
    const int cathegories=4;
    unsigned int aRegCondition[cathegories]={2,2,2,2};

    for(int i=0;i<cathegories;i++)
    {


        for(int i=0;i<aRegCondition[0];i++)
            regExp+=L".*\\d";
        regExp+=seperator;
        for(int i=0;i<aRegCondition[1];i++)
            regExp+=L".*\\W";
        regExp+=seperator;
        for(int i=0;i<aRegCondition[2];i++)
            regExp+=L".*[A-Z]";
        regExp+=seperator;
        for(int i=0;i<aRegCondition[3];i++)
            regExp+=L".*[a-z]";
        regExp+=L")(?![.\\n]).*$";// check for newline characters and end
        wregex rx(regExp);

        if (Password)
        {
            match = regex_search(Password->Buffer, mr, rx);

            if (match)
            {
                match = TRUE;
                writeLog<<"SumitPassword matches the complexity"<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                match = FALSE;
                writeLog<<"SumitPassword does not matche the complexity"<<endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            writeLog<<"SumitPassword is NULL"<<endl;
        }

        return match;
    }
```

Comment: You are being vague.  "I appended under ..." is **vague** -- what you described could be anything from "that is correct" to "that is the source of your problem".  You need to be **specific** and **complete** in your description of each step.  If you cannot be specific and complete, nobody can help you.  Well, I could link the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721766(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Does your domain password policy, do you have "Passwords must meet complexity requirements" enabled? Per [Microsoft's documentation on enabling a custom password filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecMgmt/installing-and-registering-a-password-filter-dll), this policy needs to be enabled for the password filter to be applied (when we implemented our password filter five or so years ago, I confirmed the policy was required too).

If you've got the complexity policy enabled, run a remote debugging session against LSASS.EXE (in WinDBG, you need to close the debugging session with 'qd' {quit and detach} otherwise lsass.exe terminates unexpectedly and your computer is all sorts of messed up until it reboots).

I would recommend not putting anything under InitializeChangeNotify unless you have **thorough** exception handling. Exceptions occurring through this call can create wide-spread issues. My InitializeChangeNotify is simply a return true ... which is accurate since my filter has a separate service which applies the business logic to test password validity -- if my DLL is up enough to respond to InitializeChangeNotify, then it ***is*** up.

For reference, my PasswordFilter function:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOLEAN __stdcall PasswordFilter(PUNICODE_STRING AccountName,
                                                                  PUNICODE_STRING FullName,
                                                                  PUNICODE_STRING Password,
                                                                  BOOLEAN SetOperation) {

    //build the account struct
    PasswordFilterAccount *pfAccount = new PasswordFilterAccount();
    pfAccount->AccountName = AccountName;
    pfAccount->Password = Password;

    //start an asynchronous thread to be able to kill the thread if it exceeds the timout
    HANDLE pfHandle = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, CreateSocket, (LPVOID *)pfAccount, 0, 0);

    // timeout is milliseconds. Is 30 seconds too long?
    DWORD dWaitFor = WaitForSingleObject(pfHandle, 30000); //do not exceed the timeout. 
    if (dWaitFor == WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
        //timeout exceeded
        writeWindowsEventLog("Timeout exceeded", "OPF", "ERROR", 5);
    }
    else if (dWaitFor == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        //here is where we want to be
    }
    else {
        //WAIT_ABANDONED
        //WAIT_FAILED
        writeWindowsEventLog("WAIT abandoned or failed", "OPF", "ERROR", 5);
    }

    if (pfHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE && pfHandle != 0) {
        if (CloseHandle(pfHandle)) {
            pfHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        }
    }

    return bPasswordOk;
}
```